# how to load a tab from appdelegate

Tags: objective-c, ios

My app will receive push notification and basically in the following two functions which are in the AppDelegate.m file, I would like to launch or load a tab in my app when the user receives the push notification.  I have several tabs on the app but would like to show one of them.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you're trying to switch the Tab in the TabBar programmatically? [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:i];